# Plot a vector as a line in r

Tags: r, plot, vector

I have a vector like this:

```
vec<-c(NA,1,1,NA,NA,NA,1,NA)
```

How can I plot it like this:
[image]

I already have a plot ready, I just want to add a line like above to my current plot. So I tried using line:

```
line(vec)
```

But I am having an error. How can I achieve what I want to do?

Comment: I just tried `lines`, and it did not work if I use NA in the vector. It did show up on my plot if I replace NA with 0, but it is just a straight line with no breaks where the 0 should go

Comment: `ylim` didn't need to be set and both of them are the same

Comment: Try `plot(1:length(vec),vec,type = 'b')`

Comment: This works! But how can I combine the two plots together? Right now I got two plots, but I want to add the line to my current plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?
Note the use of `seq_along` as x axis coordinates. And of a plot of type `"n"`, meaning no plot, just set the plot area with appropriate width and height.

```r
vec<-c(NA,1,1,NA,NA,NA,1,NA)

plot(seq_along(vec), vec, type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
lines(seq_along(vec), vec, xlab = "", ylab = "")
points(seq_along(vec), vec, pch = 19, xlab = "", ylab = "")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

The data set `cars` is probably not the best example since the axis ranges do not match `vec`'s, but here is a plot.

```r
vec <- c(NA,1,1,NA,NA,NA,1,NA)

plot(cars, main = "Stopping Distance versus Speed", xlim = c(0, 25))
lines(seq_along(vec), vec, xlab = "", ylab = "")
points(seq_along(vec), vec, pch = 19, xlab = "", ylab = "")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I just tried it, but it still couldn't give me any lines on my plot. I tried it with `plot(cars, main = "Stopping Distance versus Speed")
vec<-c(NA,1,1,NA,NA,NA,1)
lines(x=seq_along(vec),y=vec,col="red")`

Comment: @msening See if the edit is what you are looking for.

Comment: I think it is! I tried it on `cars` and it works! Thank you! So by adding `xlim` we can force the two to be plotted together?

Comment: @msening Yes, many times the plots are missing something because those elements are outside the plot area. `xlim` and `ylim` are a natural way solve that. (Another is to takes logarithms, when the scales are very different).